# javafx scene builder action handler for text field

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a method in my controller class for auto completion functionality of text field. That method is connected to the text field in the scene builder but it's not working because i'm not passing correct parameter for event handling in my method. I have tried the following:

- **autoComplete(ActionEvent event)**
- **autoComplete(KeyEvent event)**

Can anyone tell what parameter should i pass to fix this problem?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are doing with the event, but won't passing ```Event event``` cover the load? Unless you actually need something from the specific subtype of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try to listen for change in the text and do the autocompletion logic afterwards

```
textField.textProperty().addListener( e -> {
    System.out.println(textField.getText());
});
```